# firebase rule for admin

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

[image: This image for structure data]

I wrote this but its not working:

`isAdmin()`: not working

`isLogin()`: working well

```
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
            allow read, write : if false;
        }
        
        function isLogin() {
          return request.auth != null
        }
        
        function isAdmin() {
          return isLogin() && 
          get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin == true
        }
      
    
        // allow for only auth & is admin
        match /users/{userId} {
          allow read, write : if isAdmin();
        }
    
      }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you sure the user making the query is indeed an admin? Can you show the code making the query? For this use case, using custom claims is probably better, https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the **database** variable as an argument in your function like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
            allow read, write : if false;
        }
        
        function isLogin() {
          return request.auth != null
        }
        
        function isAdmin(database) {
          return isLogin() && 
          get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin == true
        }
      
    
        // allow for only auth & is admin
        match /users/{userId} {
          allow read, write : if isAdmin(database);
        }
    
      }
}
```